# Simple preg replace I cannot figure out

Tags: php, preg-replace

I spent a few hours trying to figure this out and I just cannot get it.  I simply want the `preg_replace` to only remove the `http://` out of an anchor tag.  I tried this `str_replace` but as you already know it doesn't work inside a `preg_replace`:

```
$site = preg_replace('/<a href="(.*?)">/','<a href="mypage.php?url='. str_replace("http://", "", "$1") .'">', $site);
```

I want only want the any anchor link to remove the `http://` part out, but not for image links so it wont break < img src="....." >
tags. Only urls for anchor tags. Actually if you could make it remove `http://` and the www. part out too that would be great.  So http://google.com or http://www.google.com will appear as google.com. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$1` isn't a real variable, so you can't use `str_replace` on it.

Try this :

```
$site = preg_replace('/<a href="http:\/\/(.*?)">/','<a href="mypage.php?url=$1">', $site);
```

By just putting the http:// in the pattern you ensure that it won't be in `$1`. Of course you do need to escape the `/` by putting a backslash in front of it. Hence the `:\/\/`

If you need this to work for https as well, try :

```
$site = preg_replace('/<a href="https?:\/\/(.*?)">/','<a href="mypage.php?url=$1">', $site);
```

The `?` after the `s` will allow it to either be there or not. Of course this will rewrite the link `https://google.com` to `mypage.php?url=google.com` which may not be what you want (you no longer know whether it was http or https)

For the www. part :

```
$site = preg_replace('/<a href="https?:\/\/(www\.|)(.*?)">/','<a href="mypage.php?url=$2">', $site);
```

Comment: Haha, great job thanks so much.  Preg match alone prevented me from having a career in programming.